# Sesiones con Xamarin Secure Storage Plugin

Tags: c#, xamarin, sesiones, local-storage

Hola amigos estoy desarrollando un app que consume un web service , mi pregunta es con respecto a las sesiones en **Xamarin**, quisiera saber alguien podría orientarme de como manejar este tópico,¿Cómo generar y mantener sesiones en xam?, mi servicio web me devulve un token (bearer), que quisiera usar para confirmar mi sesión, pero tambien debo asegurarme de que la sesión no se cierre cuando la aplicación se cierre o cuando no este activa.Leí que existe una librería de nombre **Secure Storage Plugin** con la cual tengo entendido que puedo guardar mi token y reutilizarlo,¿Alguien sabe algo de ello? . Si alguien pudiese guiarme o linkearme un ejemplo de como hacer esto, le estaría eternamente agradecido :3

Comment: Tranquilamente puedes guardar ese token usando SQLite

Comment: @fredyfx crees tener o saber de un ejemplo o algo donde pueda ver como guardarlo y hacer uso de el?

Comment: aquí: https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=xamarin+forms+sqlite&addon=firefox&addonversion=4.0.2 :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El secure storage plugin sirve para guardar datos en la zona "encriptada" del telefono.

En el caso de iOS puede llegar a ser problematico porque esa zona no se borra cuando se desinstala la app.

Si solo quieres guardarlo para tener persistencia de un uso a otro puedes usar [Plugin.Settings](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin) que lo guarda en lo que vendria a ser las preferencias.

En todo caso yo no estoy muy de acuerdo con usar tokens para mantener sesiones en movilidad.

Lo que suelo hacer es que al iniciar la app o al restaurarla relogueo al usuario, para comprobar que sus credenciales siguen siendo válidas. Si el login es correcto lo dejo pasar de forma transparente, y si no lo vuelvo a la pantalla de login y borro las credenciales.

Para guardar usuario y password si deberias usar ese plugin que comentas.

**EDICIÓN**

Ejemplo de uso de Plugin.Settings:

Cuando instalas el plugin te crea un fichero Settings en la carpeta Helpers en todos los proyectos. Si estas en forms solo necesitas el del proyecto PCL.
En ese proyecto tienes propiedades como:

```
        private const string usuario = "usuario";
        public static string SettingsUsuario
        {
            get { return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(usuario, SettingsDefault); }
            set { AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(usuario, value); }
        }
```

Desde ese momento puedes llamar guardar o grabar llamando a la propiedad

Pero no se si eso vale para lo que tu quieres.

La norma "general" que deberias usar es.

- Configuracion de usuario que da igual que sea segura o no a
  Plugin.Settings.
- Configuracion de usuario que necesitas que se guarde
  segura a Secure Storage
- Contenido de la aplicación que tiene uso
  (creado, borrado, actualizado) a Sqlite.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu comentario, encontré que tambien puedo usar **Sqlite**, así que hasta ahora mi plan es guardar todos los datos y el token de mi usuario para manejar su sesión y el login con el servicio. Crees que sea una buena opción?

Comment: En la app que tengo yo ahora uso Secure storage para guardar el usuario y la contraseña. Plugin.Settings para guardar sus opciones de configuración y Sqlite para guardar los datos que me descargo del servidor y dar persistencia. Sqlite esta bien, pero a no ser que lo hagas a posta no esta encriptado, asi que es fácilmente hackeable.

Comment: Supongamos que resivo una serie de datos de un Json y que quiero guardarlos con **Plugin.Settings** podrías darme un ejemplo para darte la mejor respuesta? :D

Comment: El usuario @Muflar te ha dado una buena respuesta y te ha dado una buena explicación. Si ahora tienes otra duda deberías realizar una nueva pregunta y mostrar lo que has intentado, no pedir que te hagan las cosas para dar por válida una respuesta